# How does Google now I'm subscribe to Hulu?

Tags: internet, google, hulu

New level of Google creepy for me. Was searching a show and somehow it knew I'm subscribed to Hulu. Check out the pic. It says subscribed under Hulu. I have no idea how I've never used Hulu on my phone or on chrome browser.[image]!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be [on-topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). Additionally, it isn't clear what the OP is trying to ask here.

Comment: Besides being off topic for this site, you should be aware that [Google Sells Your Data](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/apple-boss-tim-cook-slams-google-and-facebook-for-selling-their-users-data-10295158.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a screenshot from an Android phone regarding "Google Now".

Comment: @JashJacob now = know. How does google know about  my Hulu  ?

Comment: @ankii - Possible in multiple ways - Example, If you made hulu subscription via Google Chromecast.

Comment: @JashJacob assuming that one can see the same thing via iphone, why not open it and get an authoritative answer?

Comment: @ankii because it is not Apple related...

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you signed into Hulu using a Gmail, or more likely Google found some connection between your Google account and Hulu account, because finding things are what they do for a business (totally not because of  some backdoor stuff that we are not supposed to know). They are just trying to make things more convenient for you while making some money off of it, its a win-win as I see it

BTW, this is the Apple StackExchange, not for Hulu nor Google nor Chrome and definitely not for the Android you are using.